Flutter - Ver todas las notificaciones recibidas
quiero implementar el envío de notificaciones a un usuario en especifico cuando otro usuario haga una acción en la app, por ejemplo el usuario X da like a una publicación del usuario Z, entonces al usuario Z le llega una notificación indicando que su publicación tiene un like. Esto se puede hacer con flutter_local_notifications, pero para poder listar todas las notificaciones recibidas, mostrar la cantidad de notificaciones leídas y no leídas existe algún plugin o se deben guardar las notificaciones en mi BD y programar la consulta a la BD para conocer el estado y mostrar todas las notificaciones de un usuario en particular (cada usuario vea sus notificaciones)?
He visto varios tutoriales de como enviar/recibir las notificaciones locales, pero nada de como listar dentro de la app las notificaciones.
Saludos.

Bienvenido al sitio, es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, si únicamente deseas una opinión obtén reputación para preguntar en [chat], te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.

Guardar en la bd -> crear api para la consulta de las notificaciones -> listar las notificaciones con ListView.builder -> Usar ChangeNotifier para notificar los cambios en las notificiaciones(cantidad)

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
